# Using if statements with jquery to limit animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I want to make a div which is animated to fly upwards on click of a link, but ONLY if the link has not been clicked previously meaning that it is still in its original position. My if statement currently looks like this:

```
$("#tutorialslink").click(function(){
 if($(".tab").position().top < "0px"){
$("#bottuts,.tab").animate({top : "-=350px"});
}

});
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix it please? I'm completely new to javascript and jquery so please forgive any ridiculous syntax errors!

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "fix"? And how many tab elements are there on the page?

Comment: Hi Dave. There are only four, made to look like tabs of a ringbinder going across the bottom of the page. Please see my comment below for current (still not working) code! Thanks

Comment: I thought the problem might be that it had to be just one element to return one position value, so I tried changing it to a different element with an id and the same position. Hasn't fixed it though.

Comment: `#bottuts,.tab` means apply to both `#bottuts` and `.tab`. You probably intended `#bottuts .tab`, which means apply to the `.tab` within `#bottuts`. Also you should have `top` in quotes to work with old browsers. Other than that Blender's answer below is fine.

Comment: (maybe your `tab` objects don't have a `position` property? `animate` will only change CSS, so if setting `top` on your object has no change, animating it won't either. You need to use `position:relative` or `absolute` or `fixed`)

Comment: Tab is set to position relative and #bottuts is on absolute. The original is right, .tab and #bottuts are both separately animated.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `.one()` function to make the click event handler detach once it has been fired:

```
$("#tutorialslink").one("click", function() {
    $("#bottuts, .tab").animate({
        top: "-=350px"
    });
});
```

Comment: I had no idea that existed.  Wow that would make a lot of code I have written a lot cleaner

Comment: I was pleased with the one function for a while but it means that if a user wants to go back to a previous tab they can't. I now have this:

          var p = $("#curmid");
    var position = p.position();
 $("#tutorialslink").click(function(){
    $(".tuttab.tabl").attr('id','curl'); 
  $(".tuttab.tabmid").attr('id','curmid'); 
  $(".tuttab.tabr").attr('id','curr');
  $("#botservices,#botcontact").hide(0);
    if($("#tutorialslink").position().top > -1){
 $("#bottuts,.tab").animate({top : "-=350px"});
}

Comment: Naturally enough this doesn't work, because position doesn't seem to have changed after the animation so it animates every time. From what I can tell it should be fine- any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: @MakrobeDnb: Can you explain your *exact* scenario and what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Certainly. What I have is four tabs across the bottom of a page. When three of them are clicked I would like them and their respective div to move up to fill the screen. If someone is already on one of the tabs and they click another one then the tabs all fly off the top of the screen which is why I want the javascript to check position:top of #tutorialslink and only animate it if it has not been moved up the screen previously. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the < operator on a string.  Just compare the top to the integer 0 like so:

```
$("#tutorialslink").click(function(){

   if($(".tab").position().top < 0){
      $("#bottuts,.tab").animate({top : "-=350px"});
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3BSw7/

```
var $tab = $(".tab");

$("#tutorialslink").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default so link isn't followed

    $tab.each(function () { // Loop through elements with 'tab' class
      var $this = $(this); // $(this) refers to each looped element

      if ($this.position().top <= 200) { // compare to a number and not a string
          $this.animate({top: "+=150px"});
      }        
    });
});
```